# Why do I get different runtimepaths depending on which API I use?

Tags: lua, neovim

I'm trying to run Neovim 0.8.1. on a Windows 11 environment.

My setup is really minimal:

- I downloaded `nvim-win64.zip` (of version 0.8.1) from Neovim's [releases page](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases) on Github.
- Extracted it and moved it to a folder at `C:\test\nvim-win64`
- Started up Neovim by executing `C:\test\nvim-win64\bin\nvim.exe`

Not using any custom config.

When inspecting my runtimepath, there are 2 ways of doing this:

- Using `:set runtimepath?` (the Vimscript way). This gives me:

```
runtimepath=~\AppData\Local\nvim,~\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site,C:\test\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime,C:\test\nvim-win64\share\nvim\runtime\pack\dist\opt\matchit,C:\test\nvim-win64\lib\nvim,~\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\after,~\AppData\Local\nvim\after
```

- Using `:lua print(vim.inspect(vim.api.nvim_list_runtime_paths()))` (the Lua way). this gives me:

```
{ "C:\\test\\nvim-win64\\share\\nvim\\runtime", "C:\\test\\nvim-win64\\share\\nvim\\runtime\\pack\\dist\\opt\\matchit", "C:\\test\\nvim-win64\\lib\\nvim" }
```

As you can see, it seems like using the Lua way I'm missing the local config directories in my runtimepath (the `~\AppData\Local\*` paths).

Why am I seeing this difference? This is blocking me from using `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` to use my own config that I typically use, because it seems like it does not get included in the `nvim_list_runtime_paths` list, but it does appear in `:set runtimepath?`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that my employer had decided to put `(` and `)` characters in my `%USERPROFILE%` environment variable, which ended up breaking a bunch of stuff (including the list I got from `nvim_list_runtime_paths`).

Putting those characters in `%USERPROFILE%` is a bad idea for many reasons, so I moved all of my files and folders out of any (sub)directory in `%USERPROFILE%` and right in `C:\`.

I also had to define `XDG_CONFIG_HOME`, `XDG_DATA_HOME` and `XDG_STATE_HOME` to point to a different location than the default location (which default within `%USERPROFILE%`).

This made all of my troubles go away!

Answer (score 1):

Nvim api function filters out non-existent directories. So there's a difference.

Comment: Oooh that's good to know. This puts me a bit further ahead. It seems like the paths that contain `~` are regarded as invalid and thus ignored by `nvim_list_runtime_paths`. I managed to get `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` not be ignored if I created my path like this: `/c/Users/MyUserName/dotfiles` (so not the normal Windows notation with `\` and `C:\`.

Comment: But this is really annoying, because when I try to use some config that installs packer at `vim.fn.stdpath('data')`, this is automatically ignored by `nvim_list_runtime_paths` and hence I can't `require` packer. Do you have any idea of how I can make Neovim understand those default `~` characters from `:set runtimepath?` ?

Comment: In Windows create ```%localappdata%\nvim\lua``` - And all what you want to require with put in ```%localappdata%\nvim\lua``` - If you have a folder in there then use the dot for an OS independent: ```require("folder.lua_source")``` (Finds: ```%localappdata%\nvim\lua\folder\lua_source.lua```)

Comment: @Koedlt I don't quite understand what are you trying to do. It is enough to make sure that the directory is created and then it will appear in the list (with "tilde" expanded).

Comment: @Matt my problem was that those directories did exist, but they weren't ending up in the list. Finally I found out the root cause of my issues. I'll post it as an answer. Thanks a bunch though, your help brought me on the right path!